# vim abbr: how to stop from generating new line?

Tags: vim, vi

in vimrc if I do

```
iab YBK \left<\right><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>
```

then when I type `YBK` I will have

```
\left<
_\right>
```

where `_` is the where the cursor stays. This is pretty much what I want except that vim automatically generates a line break before the cursor position, as what I want is

```
\left< _ \right>
```

So, how to avoid the nuisance of line break? thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior.  What line-ending style do you use in your `.vimrc` file?

Comment: @ib. interesting. Is there a command to show the line-ending style used by vim? for me, it is simply a latex enviroment, so I'm not sure the latex syntax config was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

look at [surround.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697). I think you can extend it with your own 'open/close' pairs. It has this behaviour builting for several types of pairs already. Two examples to spark your interest:

- `vS`<kbd>C-]</kbd> (wraps in `{` ... `}` with newlines around it and indenting according to the filetype indent settings
- `vS`<kbd>C-<</kbd>`para`<kbd>Enter</kbd> (wraps in `<para>` ... `</para>`), example:

.

```
the quick fox jumped over
```

(position cursor on the `q` in *quick*, press `v2eS`<kbd>C-<</kbd>`para`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Result:

```
the <para>
    quick fox
</para> jumped over
```

Edit

It appears that maybe you wanted this the other way around - ***without* linebreaks**. Well then, use `vs<para`<kbd>Enter</kbd> or `vS{` respectively, which by default don't insert linebreaks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I kinda prefer a solution that is plugin-free unless there is no intrinsic way to do it with `abbr`, but I'll give the plugin a shot if that way is impossible.